# Android rest services to call spring rest service post method as return of string

Tags: android, spring, rest, service

i have a spring rest service which has Post method to reuturn String as response

How can i catch the returned string from android rest clinet

please help ..!

Answer (score 0):

In your rest client you should have something like this:

```
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null)
        {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            response = convertStreamToString(instream);

            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }
```

And the method which converts from the stream to a string will be something like this:

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try
    {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```